# Spring boot set database configuration

Tags: spring-boot

Can any body have idea how to set database connection in a propper way,

I could do this in application.properties like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@ds047955.mylab.com:47955/myapp
```

But I'm sure that user name and password (USER:PASSWORD) shouldn't be here! Can any one tell me how to configure spring.data.mongodb.uri in propper PRODUCTION way?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the username and password using [application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

```
# MONGODB (MongoProperties)
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database= # Authentication database name.
spring.data.mongodb.database=test # Database name.
spring.data.mongodb.field-naming-strategy= # Fully qualified name of the FieldNamingStrategy to use.
spring.data.mongodb.grid-fs-database= # GridFS database name.
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost # Mongo server host.
spring.data.mongodb.password= # Login password of the mongo server.
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017 # Mongo server port.
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true # Enable Mongo repositories.
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test # Mongo database URI. When set, host and port are ignored.
spring.data.mongodb.username= # Login user of the mongo server.
```

A possible way for production would be to start your app with VM arguments. E.g.

`-Dspring.data.mongodb.username=foobar`

or use custom property placeholders to from your propertysources

`spring.data.mongodb.username=${yourapp.mongodb.username}`

The latter could also come from e.g. an environment variable that will be set on your production server.

Answer (score 0):

you create jndi context and that property you have to add in application.properties as below
spring.datasource.jndi-name = java:comp/env/jdbc/test